# Native Cross Platform Language + Environment

Tags: native, native-code

I'm wondering what *native* cross platform languages + environments are out there.

This is similar to a few other questions that other people have asked however,
there are only three requirements:

- Cross Platform
- Produce a standard binary file (.exe, elf, etc).
- <25MB minimum distributable

Binaries do not have to be native in that they compile to assembly. They just need to be self hosting (not require an external VM or interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

eForth is 8MB.  Full IDE ( command line ) and is ported to most any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lazarus is a free cross-platform and open source IDE which provides a Delphi-like development experience for Pascal and Object Pascal developers. This means the IDE contains a full GUI builder and is centered around GUI development.

It is part of a project that also creates the Free Pascal compiler, which supports many dialects of Pascal, including Delphi. There is also a standard library that contains many of the basics you'd expect.

[Lazarus and Free Pascal website](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/)